# Not able to add footerView in UTableView through XIB

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I am trying to add `FooterView(UIView)` by dragging down on `UITableview` through **XIB** but can't.

Yes we can add it programetically (`tableView.tableFooterView = myView`) & also works with dragging view in Storyboard,
**But I want right from XIB.**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a Xib. If you think about it, a storyboard is somewhat like a collection of Xib files. Thus, in a storyboard you can add a footer view as a kind of 'xib' embedded in that storyboard. A pure xib cannot contain multiple child xib's, so what you want is not possible unfortunately.

Comment: Then how `headerView` is possible ?

Comment: Hm, good question. I just tried it and indeed it works with a header view. I'm not sure why it doesn't work with a footer view then.